# Tab order when more controls have the same tabindex?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What determines the tab order when more controls have the same `tabindex` property?

For example, after adding a texbox to an empty form the texbox's `tabindex` was 0. By duplicating the texbox (Ctrl + mouse drag) the new textbox had `tabindex` 0 too. Then I added a button and its `tabindex` was 1.

After running the program the focus was on the 2nd textbox.

Then I changed button's `tabindex` to 0 so after that all controls had `tabindex` = 0 and after running the program the focus was on the button which was added last.

Does that mean that in case of multiple controls with the same `tabindex` property the tab order will be the **opposite of order of adding** the controls to the form? Seems as the tab order of the controls which share the same `tabindex` is **just the opposite of their order of appearance in `Form.Designer.cs` file**.

Or is it that button control always has priority over textbox control when they both share the same `tabindex`?

Is that documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN [Control.TabIndex Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex)

> A tab index can consist of any valid integer greater than or equal to
> zero, lower numbers being earlier in the tab order. If more than one
> control on the same parent control has the same tab index, the z-order
> of the controls determines the order to cycle through the controls.

And a bit of a nuance as well:

> For a control to be included in the tab order, its TabStop property
> must be set to true.

So, you're seeing controls with the same `TabIndex` value tab in reverse order from the code behind file due to the z-index value.

Comment: Do you maybe know what will happen if the controls have the same z-index?

Comment: @Chupo_cro - you could always just experiment with different tab orders and z-index and see what happens :)